# Set Label Visible within ActionPerformed using AWT

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I have a button that should trigger a text appearing in the panel, but I'm not been able to change the visibility of the button

I don't get why this piece of code isnt working(when I click button1, label doesnt appear).

```
public class AWTFrame extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    Panel p1 = new Panel();
    Label l1 = new Label("You clicked in button1");

    public AWTFrame(){
        super("Example!");
        setSize(450, 250);

        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Button b1 = new Button("Button 1");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        Button b2 = new Button("Button 2");

        p1.add(b1);
        p1.add(b2);
        p1.add(l1);

        l1.setVisible(false);

        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        l1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `validate()` the panel so the layout manager can be invoked:

```
    l1.setVisible(true);
    p1.validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you update a component whilst the frame is visible you need to revalidate the frame.

Use `p1.validate();`

Comment: I meant validate, accidentally put revalidate as it's AWT. I posted and just as I posted yours came up and I realized my mistake. Was an easy one to make, I guess. It's fixed now. :)